# Having two partition of Home on ubuntu, increasing home

Tags: partitioning, swap, home-directory

I have a bit of space limitation on my Home partition. The configuration of my partition is:

- A windows Recovery
- Drive C windows
- Drive D windows
- Deleted and formated to EXt4 to add to ubuntu
- 695 MB boot
- 30.26 Root
- 20.49 Swap
- 39.11 Home

[A screenshot of my drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lee8q.png)
I freed my windows D partition (21.48 GB). I really need to increase my home size:

1. Can I just partition this new freed drive as home as well? Can I have two seperate partitions as home at the same time?
2. Alternatively, can I change the swap to new freed space, and expand the home (the last partition to the old swap that is just before it). In this way, because the start of the home partition will change, will I loost my home partition table, and have a mess? (loose data?)
3. Is there any other alternative partition I can just add instead of home? I want to use this partition for my Android studio, etc. that are eating my home Memory.
   Thank you for your help and experience.

Comment: Option 1 will not work. 2 and 3 are possible, as is a combination of 2 and 3.  Why do you have 20 GB of swap? DO you have a LiveCD?

Comment: Thanks, I have 16GB ram and I read that swap need to be 1.5 times the ram size.

Comment: if you do not hibernate, swap can be much smaller. Which option would you like to do? I can post an answer.

Comment: I would prefer the second one. But I am not sure if the start location of the home partition changes, the boot table still identifies it and the data in it are safe. Thanks.

Comment: So, is it fine when the start of the home partition changes?

Comment: I posted an answer for both options,

Answer (score 0):

## For option 2

A LiveCD or similar media is required because it is not recommended to manipulate a mounted partition.

Boot into the LiveCD and run gparted.

Delete the "D" partition, then make a swap partition there.
Click on partition --> information, and write down the UUID of the new swap partition.

Use a text editor to edit /etc/fstab. The entry for the swap partition will look like this:

```
UUID=<UUID>  none    swap      sw    0       0
```

Rplace the UUID with the one for the new swap partition.

Again in gparted, delete the old swap partition, then grow home to fill the empty space.

## For Option 3

Live media is not necessary for this option.

Run gparted. Delete the "D" partition and create an ext4 partition in the free space.
Click partiton --> information. and write down the UUID of the new partition

Now create a new folder in your home folder.
For auto mounting, edit /etc/fstab to add the line:

```
UUID=<UUID> /home/<username>/<newfolder>  ext4   default     0       2
```

replace UUID, username and newfolder as appropriate for your system.

and reboot

## note: be sure when copying the UUID to /et/fstab as a wrong number will cause a boot error.